# Prove that anti derivative does not exist without Darboux’s theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{if } x\le 0,\\
2 & \textrm{if } 0<x\le 1,\\
3 & \textrm{if } x>1.
\end{cases}
$$
I tried a couple of ways but all of them lead to Darboux’s theorem. How do I prove this without Darboux’s theorem?

Comment: Mean value theorem is the key. Use it to show that derivatives can't have simple discontinuity.

Comment: Please state a coherent question in the body of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: As you know, if $F'= 0$ on an interval, then $F$ is constant that interval. Now if $f$ is the function you describe and $F' = f$ everywhere, then $F(x) - x$ is constant on $(-1,0]$ and $F(x) - 2x$ is constant on $(0,1).$ Thus $F'(x) =x+c$ on $(-1,0]$ and $F(x) = 2x + d$ on $(0,1).$ Is it possible for $F'(0)$ to exist in this scenario?

Comment: Thanks! This helped.

Comment: This one is another smart and new way (for me at least) to use mean value theorem. +1